# Deploy GeoServer layer located in PostgreSQL as a vector layer to ASP.NET application

Tags: openlayers, geojson, wfs

I try to deploy one of my GeoServer layers located in PostgreSQL named "ADA" as a vector layer to ASP.NET application. What should be the URL link?

```
    const merkez = ol.proj.fromLonLat([35.31535, 37.00505]);
    const merkezzoom = 12.3
    var ada_wfs_src = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
            return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=AdanaMebis:ADA&maxFeatures=1500&outputFormat=application/json';

        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
            maxZoom: 19
        }))

    });
    
    var ada_wfs = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: ada_wfs_src,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                width: 2
            })
        })
    });
         var googleLayerHybrid2 = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: "Google Terrain & Rods",
        source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
    });
    const view = new ol.View({
        center: merkez,
        zoom: merkezzoom,
        maxZoom: 24,
        minZoom: 8

        //extent: [35.0647, 36.8694, 35.5693, 37.1577],

    });



    const map = new ol.Map({

        target: 'map',
        loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
        layers: [
            googleLayerHybrid2, ada_wfs 
        ],
        view: view,
    });
```

---

I use ASP.NET & GeoServer 2.21 & ol 6.14.1 version ESPG:4326.
The JavaScript runs above inside the Default.aspx after body section finished..
When I Start my applicaiton googleLayerHybrid2 is coming but ada_wfs not..
I checked the console but see there is no error.
So (No error no map).. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I doubt WFS vector layer will work with tile loading strategy. What do you get in the network section of browser debugger? What kind of WFS request are generated? See WFS example at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html.

Comment: var ada_wfs_src = new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url: function (extent) {
                return (
                    'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                    'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=AdanaMebis:ADA&' +
                    'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
                    'bbox=' +
                    extent.join(',') +
                    ',EPSG:4326'
                );
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
        });

Comment: Again, what do you see in network section of browser debugger? What are the results of the WMS calls?

Comment: And again, if you want some help, what do you see in network section of browser debugger? What are the results of the WMS calls?

Comment: I noticed that geoserver bbox is responding epsg3857. here is the respond.  Request: getFeature
    service = WFS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    query[0]:
        filter = [  bbox ReferencedEnvelope[3904589.7306463914 : 3957983.8277260773, 4425841.329639036 : 4453780.101366779] ]
        srsName = EPSG:4326
        typeName[0] = {AdanaAsri}ADA
    outputFormat = application/json
    resultType = results
28 058 20:58:55 INFO   [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON